# Use hotkeys to send command to docker compose containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file in which one container uses `nodemon` to watch for changes and restart `node`. Anyhow I would prefer to restart on a hotkey, like `shift+ctrl+R`.

Is it possible to pass commands to docker containers from the docker compose shell using hotkeys?

Otherwise how would you solve my specific case? Maybe have two terminals open, and I will send the command `docker compose -f infra/dev.compose.yml restart gateway`  for example?